# WPF Toolbar with Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

My question follows this question: [WPF Module toolbar prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808342/wpf-module-toolbar-prism)

Is it possible to use a WPF Toolbar as a Prism Region? What I want to do is something like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainNavigationRegion">

        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</DockPanel>
```

Basically, what I want is my modules being able to populate the toolbar buttons in a navigation region, but still keep the properties of a Toolbar (collapse when all the buttons don't fit).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. And the solution is already there: you have to create a custom region adapter, exactly as it's described in the answer you posted a link to.

Comment: The "protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()" method is a method from the custom class "MyToolbar" ? Sorry, maybe this is a very stupid question but I am very new to Prism. And then MyToolbar class inherits from ToolBar? And the DockPanel and the ToolBarTray that contains MyToolbar, is them defined in MyToolBar class or in the Shell?

Comment: No, this is a method in your PRISM application bootstrapper. You don't need to write your own toolbar, but rather you need to create a `RegionAdapter`-derived class that can adapt the PRISM's regions to your toolbar's items.

Comment: @dymanoid: this is my "ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()" method : protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(){
            RegionAdapterMappings regionAdapterMappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
            regionAdapterMappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ToolBar), new ToolBarRegionAdapter());
            return regionAdapterMappings;
        }
and I get this error: 'Prism.ToolBarRegionAdapter' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. 
However, my ToolBarRegionAdapter has no constructors, it hinerits from RegionAdapterBase<ToolBar>

Answer (score 0):

Basically in PRISM every region will be separate usercontrol/project meaning plug and play of modules,You can do one thing create toolbar or Ribbon panel in one user control and register that view in bootstraper, as usual then bind respective view in Shell.xaml .